# Applying a filter on the output voice from AVSpeechSynthesizer's Voice?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

Is there any way to apply a filter on AVSpeechSynthesizer's voice or changing it's pitch? or even using another TTS API for iOS that we can change the way they sound? or Can we record the TTS voice without it being played and then playing it after the pitch of it's voice has been modified by us?

Comment: have you checked AVSpeechUtterance class ?

Comment: I dont want to change the speed of speaking, i want to change the pitch of the output voice to make it sound like a little baby for example, the same stuff that we can do with recorded voices, is there a way to record TTS voice without being played and then playing it after applying some changes to the pitch of it? this is what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the speech synthesizer you must create an AVSpeechUtterance object. The utterance lets you set a number of properties including pitch. Changing pitch doesn't affect the rate of speech. Example of usage:

```
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: textToSpeak.text!)
    utterance.pitchMultiplier = pitchValue
    utterance.rate = rate.value
    utterance.volume = volume.value
    utterance.voice = voice
```